# Why can I not seem to get a complete file path?

Tags: python, directory, path

I am trying to create a simple script which will create a new directory in the same directory that the script is run from, but it always creates it in my `C:\Users\name` directory. Right now I'm trying to get it to simply create the new directory on my desktop (`C:\Users\name\Desktop`), but it always stops short.

```
import os

directory = "Photos not in both folders"
parent_dir = os.getcwd()
print(parent_dir)
path = os.path.join(parent_dir, directory)
os.mkdir(path)
print(path)
```

The result should be this:

```
C:\Users\name\Desktop\Photos not in both folders.
```

But ends up as:

```
C:\Users\name\Photos not in both folders.
```

Comment: what's your `parent_dir`?

Comment: this is telling you that your current working directory is `C:\Users\name`, not `C:\Users\name\Desktop`. You can use `os.chdir("C:\Users\name\Desktop")` to choose the directory and then you can just do `os.mkdir(directory)` line after that.

Answer (score 0):

this is the code I used to get the path where my program is running, in case you are creating an exe the path internally change.

```
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
   dirname = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
elif __file__:
   dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```